# Set pipeline variable to the string.replace output from another build variable?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm struggling to do something simple in an ADO build pipeline.  I want to create a variable to hold a docker image tag value that is generated from the source branch name.  Since it's pretty common to have 'refs/heads/' to prefix your actual git branch I'm trying to do multiple stages of string replacements.

For example say I have a feature branch called: "feature/login".  My ado pipeline will see that as "refs/heads/feature/login" but ultimately docker doesn't like '/' in tags so I need to create a variable with a value "feature__login".

So I'm trying to do this in two "steps" by having two pipeline variables

```yaml
variables:
  BRANCH_NAME: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
  BRANCH_TAG: '$[replace(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], '/', '__')]
```

BRANCH_NAME will have the 'refs/heads' removed and BRANCH_TAG will use BRANCH_NAME and repace the remaining '/'s with '__'s.  But I get this error when I create my pipeline :
"(Line: 5, Col: 50): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key."

I've tried to set up these variables a few ways but can't seem to get the right syntax.  How do you run multiple replace expressions to set a variable to the output of those expressions?

Comment: You have an unmatched single quote at the start of the expression   `'$[replace(variables['BRANCH_NAME'], '/', '__')]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
variables:
- name: BRANCH_TAG
  value: $[replace(replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/', ''),'/', '_')]
```

Comment: And replace `Build.SourceBranch` with `Build.SourceBranchName` to automatically remove the `refs/heads`.

Comment: Build.SourceBranchName only give you leaf name...if you have refs/heads/release/V1 it will only give you V1...you may want release_V1 as tag...this gives you that.